# Why does opening google maps via intent on android yield different results than the search box?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-urls

I am working on an app that allows you to text an address to an android device and have that device open maps directly to navigation with the texted address as the destination. Currently, I use the navigation intent described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation). However, I am finding that the intent queries often lead to a range of addresses being returned as opposed to the address that I sent. Confusingly, if I put the exact same text into the maps search box, it resolves to a single address with no issue. This happens with many addresses, and I have no idea why.

As an example, if I send the following intent:

```
google.navigation:q=+500+SE+Harvard+street+minneapolis+mn&m=d
```

Maps is opened directly to navigation, but instead with the destination of a range of addresses, and in this case does not even contain the number in my query (note the 615-601 range), as can be seen by backing out of navigation:

[image: Navigation via intent result]

However, if I type the exact same query into the search box (500 SE Harvard street minneapolis mn), the address resolves perfectly:

[image: Search box result]

This seems to happen with many addresses, and can be arbitrarily far away from the actual destination. It is very important that the addresses come up correctly as my users will be unable to manually correct the mistakes. The most confusing thing is the search box seems to be consistently accurate with the exact same query, so I don't know why the intent isn't working the same way. Is there something I am doing wrong with the navigation intents? Many thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I have found that switching the app to incognito mode fixes the issue. I'd be very interested to know what in my user account affects the address resolution if anyone knows!

Comment: I tried to replicate this on my end using the sample `query` and `mode` you provided, but I am getting the expected `500 SE Harvard Street, Minneapolis, MN, USA` address. 
Can you please clarify if you are still getting the 615-601 address range? If so, may I know what is the version of your Google Maps app?

Comment: This is Maps version 10.47.1 Interestingly, if I switch to incognito mode, I reliably get the correct address! This leads me to ask - why / in what way does user account info affect address lookups?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without internal knowledge of the Google Maps application.

Comment: I tried signing in and signing out of my Google Account when I run my app using the sample query you provided but I still can't replicate the issue. I am still getting the expected `500 SE Harvard Street, Minneapolis, MN, USA` address, on the Google Maps app version 10.48.1.

This issue has also been reported on the Google Issue Tracker ([Issue 163610907](https://issuetracker.google.com/163610907)) but it can't be reproduced as well. I would suggest that you add more reproducing steps or more details on the issue mentioned so that this can be investigated further.

Comment: Other than actually signing in as my google user, I'm not sure what more context would be most likely to reproduce the issue. I am running android 10 version 4.4.177-19000400 but it looks like the Google Issue was a different version so I would assume it's something with the user context itself.